# WPF - Create reusable style with variables/parameters

Tags: wpf, styles

I have an WPF application which contains several TabItems. Each TabItem is different from each other, with a text and an icon.

This is how the TabItem´s style is defined:

```
<TabItem.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                        <Setter Property="Header">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Margin="10,0,0,0" Height="40" Width="40" Source="Images/IconLeafGrey.png"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="This is the heading" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource Heading2}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Border Name="Border" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="6,6,0,0" >
                                            <Border.Background>
                                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#f5f7f8" Offset="0.0" />
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#c5d0dd" Offset="1.0" />
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                            </Border.Background>
                                            <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ContentSource="Header" Margin="5,2,0,2"/>
                                        </Border>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#ebedee" Offset="0.0" />
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#88a2bd" Offset="1.0" />
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Header">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <Image Margin="10,0,0,0" Height="40" Width="40" Source="Images/IconLeaf.png"/>
                                            <TextBlock Text="This is the heading" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource Heading2}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>

                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TabItem.Style>
```

So instead of writing this XAML markup for each TabItem, I would like to define this style once in my ResourceDictionary, but with the Icon and the Text property as optional parameters. So I afterwards could define a TabItem like this:

```
<TabItem Width="250" Height="60" Style="{StaticResource CustomTabItem}" >
```

I´ve read that it isnt directly possible for a style to accept parameters like this, but it should be posible with some sort of binding. I havent found out exactly how though, so I really hope you can help.

Kind regards.

Comment: You can create styles [Based On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon.aspx) the main style which only overrides the Icon and Text properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of doing it would be, if you have fixed number of `TabItems` and you dont want to generate the `TabItems` through `ItemsSource` `Binding` on TabControl. Then in your `TabItem.Style` you can use `Resource` keys to get the Text and Source like:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
         <Image Margin="10,0,0,0" Height="40" Width="40" Source="{DynamicResource Image1}"/>
         <TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource Header}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource Heading2}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
     </StackPanel>
```

and for your TabItems you can define these resources:

```
     <TabItem Width="250" Height="60" Style="{StaticResource CustomTabItem}">
         <TabItem.Resources>
               <System:String x:Key="Header">TabItem1</System:String>
               <System:String x:Key="Image1">image/1.png</System:String>
               <System:String x:Key="Image2">image/2.png</System:String>
          </TabItem.Resources>
      </TabItem>
       <TabItem Width="250" Height="60" Style="{StaticResource CustomTabItem}">
         <TabItem.Resources>
               <System:String x:Key="Header">TabItem2</System:String>
               <System:String x:Key="Image1">image/3.png</System:String>
               <System:String x:Key="Image2">image/4.png</System:String>
          </TabItem.Resources>
      </TabItem>
```

Also you will need to update your `Style` to set the `HeaderTemplate` instead of `Header`

```
     <Style x:Key="CustomTabItem" TargetType="TabItem">
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image x:Name="HeaderImage" Margin="10,0,0,0" Height="40" Width="40" Source="Images/IconLeafGrey.png"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource Header}" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="HeaderImage" Property="Source" Value="Images/IconLeaf.png"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>

            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Name="Border" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="6,6,0,0" >
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#f5f7f8" Offset="0.0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#c5d0dd" Offset="1.0" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ContentSource="Header" Margin="5,2,0,2"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#ebedee" Offset="0.0" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="#88a2bd" Offset="1.0" />
                                        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Thanks alot, It seems to be working... almost!
Problem is, when I set the style on two or more TabItems, Visual studio warns me with "Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first". And if i run the application it fails with 'Set property 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Style' threw an exception.' 

Ive fiddled with it, and the error goes away if I remove the whole Header part from the style... Any idea?

Comment: can you share how are you defining the resources?

Comment: I´ve now updated the question with how I define the resource. Dont know if this is the way to do it, but comments arent able to support that many characters?

Comment: actually i wanted to know the how you are defining TabItem.Resources... you have added the code twice to TabItem Style

Comment: Ah sorry. This is how I define the TabItem:

    <TabItem Style="{StaticResource CustomTabItem}" >
                        <TabItem.Resources>
                            <System:String x:Key="Header">TabItem1</System:String>
                        </TabItem.Resources>
                    </TabItem>

Comment: you are getting this error because you have set the Stackpanel as the header and changing it in trigger... try using the HeaderTemplate as in my updated answer

Comment: Thanks alot, it works like a charm now. 
I gotta research it in order to understand it though. Anyways, thanks alot! :)

Answer (score 3):

You just need to set the `TabItem.DataContext` to an object that contains values for your `TextBlock` and `Image` controls:

In code:

```
public class TabItemData
{
    public string ImageSource { get; set; }
    public string Heading { get; set; }
}
```

In your `Style` in XAML:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image Margin="10,0,0,0" Height="40" Width="40" Source="{Binding ImageSource}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Heading}" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        Style="{StaticResource Heading2}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

In your view model:

```
public class TabControlViewModel
{
    public TabControlViewModel()
    {
        TabItemData = new TabItemData() { Header = "Some header", 
            ImageSource = "Images/IconLeafGrey.png" };
    }

    public TabItemData TabItemData { get; set; }
}
```

In XAML:

```
<TabItem DataContext="{Binding TabItemData}">
    ...
</TabItem>
```

Of course, I've left out some initialisation of the data objects and the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface which you should implement, but I hope you get the idea.